# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'x')

Tags: angular, express, mean-stack

I am new to MEAN stack, and trying to get some basic posts.  I am getting **TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'title')** when issuing post.  This works when changing todo-route.js **from**

title: req.body.title,

content: req.body.content

To

title: "SomeTextTitle",

content: "Some Content"

I have a disconnect on how the req body is passed to the post function

**Index.js**
[image]

**todo-route.js**

[image]

**todo-repo.js**

[image]

Comment: Please don't post screenshots in place of code

Comment: The error means the property "title" does not exist on the property "body", which in return means tou have not provided a "body" to your request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you haven't parse your request body. Use body Parser if not using.

Comment: Simply had to install bodyparser and  add the following lines to index.js
 
`var bodyParser = require('body-parser')`

`app.use(bodyParser.json())`